# Не показывать ли уведомление участнику, если в вопросе мало текста и много кода?

Tags: предложение, вопросы, качество-вопроса

На англоязычном SO нельзя задать вопрос, в котором мало текста и много кода. Появляется предупреждение и система не даёт отправить такой вопрос. Здесь же часто появляются вопросы состоящие исключительно из кода (прямо сейчас на главной минимум два таких) и хорошо ещё, если в заголовке будет написано, в чём проблема.

Не ввести ли здесь такое же правило, как на английском SO?

Answer (score 3):

Правильней тогда сформулировать вопрос как "стоит ли показывать **уведомление** участнику, если в вопросе нет ничего, кроме кода?".

Запрещать вопросы - не самое лучше решение. А вот выводить уведомление в случае, если код не сопровождается текстом - вполне неплохое.

С другой стороны, уже сейчас же есть механизмы для таких ситуаций:

- В комментариях можно попросить автора вопроса добавить подробностей.
- Если не было эффекта от этого, то закрыть с причиной, например, "непонятна суть вопроса".

Comment: Переименовал, но как по мне, так невозможность задать такой вопрос = такие вопросы запрещены.

Comment: @Эникейщик запрет - это уже что-то жёсткое. А вот уведомления - более лайтовая форма. По крайней мере, я так это вижу (: